# How did Arthur Dayne know what Ned Stark looked like?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones s06e03, in the Tower of Joy scene, six Northeners (including Ned Stark and Howland Reed) fight against two kingsguards, Arthur Dayne and Oswell Whent. Before the fight, there is a short conversation that starts with:

> Arthur Dayne: "Lord Stark."
>
> Ned Stark: "I was looking for you on the Trident."

How did Arthur Dayne know it was Ned Stark? Had they met before? If not, did someone tell him that Ned Stark was riding there?

Comment: I'd have to rewatch the scene but was Ned wearing livery in Stark colors? In the books characters often deduce a persons identity by using their house and probable age to pluck them out of the family tree. Sort of like how someone could ID a sports player just by knowing their team and number and memorizing the roster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's safe to assume that everyone met everyone at the tourney of Harrenhal.

Comment: That's *Ser* Arthur Dayne, Sword of the Morning to ya.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do not know if show has shown this or not but as per books Arthur Dayne was present at [Tourney of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arthur_Dayne) (That's the Tourney where Rhaegar met Lyanna and later ran away with her with help of none other than his close friend Arthur Dayne). Eddard Stark was also present there. So it is plausible that Dayne met the younger son of Lord Rickard Stark, Warden of the North, second in line to seat of the Kings of Winter after his elder brother Brandon.

Even if they did not meet, it is most likely that the Starks being nobles of a great house were granted seats in the VIP Pavilion of Lord Whent & King himself. It is a tradition that jousters turn to salute the host of the tourney and King (If present). Arthur rode in the lists at the tourney and thus he must have saluted the host, where he might have seen the "Shy Wolf" Eddard Stark.

Not to mention, [Ashara Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ashara_Dayne) (Sister of Arthur Dayne) danced with Eddard Stark at Harrenhal and supposedly she and Eddard fell in love with each other. Being a dutiful brother, Arthur might have been keeping an eye out for his sister (Seeing which of the young lordlings and knights were hitting on his sister. Fun fact, his own sworn brother Barristan Selmy was also secretly in love with Ashara) as well, thus getting to know Eddard Stark.

In conclusion, it is hard to assume that Arthur Dayne was not familiar with Eddard Stark.

Comment: Has Ashara Dayne even been mentioned in the show?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I am not watching the current season since they made pig's ear out of the last one (Or the one before it).

Comment: Also, you're correct the Tourney at Harrenhall has not been shown (might have been mentioned though).

Comment: I'd add to that Ned's heraldry would have given it away to Arthur.

Comment: @Mooz Ah yes I broke my vow to not watch the show (Once again). In that episode, I don't think Ned was flying his heraldry. But you are right that mostly nobles guessed each other's name by their heraldry and age. Mostly they knew about family tree of major houses.

Comment: @Aegon I've become a bit of a GoT denier, but I still watch. Can't resist. Lol.